# Ayuda con evento PageIndexChanging al filtrar un gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un gridview que carga datos de SQL Server, y he agredado un Dropdowlist para añadir otros datos y filtrar ese gridview, el problema ahora es que cuando filtro el gridview y cambio a la siguiente pagina "se pierde el filtro".
Aqui mi codigo:

```html
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
    loadgrid(); //carga los datos originales al grid
    cajeros();
    }
    }
    
    public void loadgrid()
    {
    try
    {
    con.Open();
    string query = "select * from TABLA";
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    ex.ToString();
    }
    }

    public void cajeros()
    {
    string query = "select id, Nombre from Cajeros";
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Cajeros");
    Cajeros.DataSource = ds.Tables["Cajeros"];
    Cajeros.DataValueField = "id";
    Cajeros.DataTextField = "Nombre";
    Cajeros.DataBind();
    }        

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    loadgrid(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    ex.ToString();
    }
    }

    //metodo para filtrar el gridiview de acuerdo a la opcion seleccionada en el dropdownlist
    
    protected void Cajeros_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
    con.Open();
    string query = "select * from TABLA where idCajero="+ Cajeros.SelectedValue+";
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te falta adicionar una validación más para mantener el filtro y que no se pierda al cambiar de página:

Mencionar que estoy suponiendo que el primer registro de tu lista de Cajeros es "Todos" para que muestre los cajeros sin ningún filtro:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        loadgrid(); //carga los datos originales al grid
        cajeros();
    }
}

public void loadgrid()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "select * from TABLA";
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}

public void loadgridByCajeroId(int idCajero)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "select * from TABLA where idCajero='"+ idCajero +"'";
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}

public void cajeros()
{
    //Código cero es equivalente a sin filtros
    string query = "select 0 id, 'Todos' Nombre union  select id, Nombre from Cajeros";
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Cajeros");
    Cajeros.DataSource = ds.Tables["Cajeros"];
    Cajeros.DataValueField = "id";
    Cajeros.DataTextField = "Nombre";
    Cajeros.DataBind();
} 

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

       if(Cajeros.SelectedIndex <= 0){
           loadgrid();
       }
       else{
           loadgridByCajeroId(int.Parse(Cajeros.SelectedValue.ToString()));
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       ex.ToString();
   }
}

//método para filtrar el gridview de acuerdo a la opción seleccionada en el dropdownlist

protected void Cajeros_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Cajeros.SelectedIndex <= 0){
        loadgrid();
    }
    else{
        loadgridByCajeroId(int.Parse(Cajeros.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que estaba buscando